# Access template parameters in another template

Tags: c++, templates

In  below code :

```
class foo{};
class bar{};

template<class Type1=foo,class Type2=bar>
class A{};

template <class T= A<>>
class B
{
 public:
    void func(typename T::Type1 a){} //error  'Type1' : is not a member of 'A<foo,bar>'
};

int main()
{
    B<> b;
    b.func(foo()); //error
}
```

I want to access `B` template's parametr(`Type1` and `Type2` in this case ) How can I make it work ?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to "export" the types, i.e .declare them as public types of your class template. For example

```
template<class T1=foo,class T2=bar>
class A
{
 public:
  typedef T1 Type1;
  typedef T2 Type2;
};
```

C++11 style

```
template<class T1=foo,class T2=bar>
class A
{
 public:
  using Type1 = T1;
  using Type2 = T2;
};
```

Comment: `typedef Type1 Type1;` is an illegal construction. See [temp.local] 14.6.1/6: "A template-parameter shall not be redeclared within its scope (including nested scopes)."